# Tcolorbox inside align environement

Tags: equations, align, tcolorbox

I wonder if it's possible to align the coloured equal signs. I have used tcolorboxes between align environments. I doubt so but, is there a way of using tcolorboxes within an align environement? Would it be possible to tell a second align environment to resume a previous one?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{AuxCalc}{
notitle,
colframe=black!75!white,
colback=black!20!white
}

\newtcolorbox{AuxCalc2}{
notitle,
colframe=black!75!white,
colback=black!10!white
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    1 &= 2 \\
    1 &= 2 \\
\end{align*}

\begin{AuxCalc}

    \begin{align*}
        14312 &= 2 \\
        1 &= 12342 \\
    \end{align*}
        
    \begin{AuxCalc2}
        \begin{align*}
            1 &= 2 \\
            1 &= 2 \\       
        \end{align*}
    \end{AuxCalc2}
    
    \begin{align*}
        11235132 &= 2 \\
        123513251 &= 2 \\
    \end{align*}
    
\end{AuxCalc}


\begin{align*}
    12341 &= 2 \\
    112512351 &= 2 \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: You should try to play with the TikZ library `tikzmark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a particularly attractive approach, but it amounts to studying the areas you want aligned, in search of the widest left-side component and widest right-side component.  You save those components with `\savewidel` and `\savewider`.  Then, for every `align` type environment you wish to conform to overall alignment, if it does not already possess the widest left/right elements, you call one argument from the left and/or right sides of the environment into `\setwidel` and `\setwider`, which basically places the argument in a box the "widel" or "wider" width, with proper right or left alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{AuxCalc}{
notitle,
colframe=black!75!white,
colback=black!20!white
}

\newtcolorbox{AuxCalc2}{
notitle,
colframe=black!75!white,
colback=black!10!white
}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\widemathl
\newsavebox\widemathr
\newcommand\savewidel[1]{\savebox\widemathl{$\displaystyle#1$}}
\newcommand\savewider[1]{\savebox\widemathr{$\displaystyle#1$}}
\newcommand\setwidel[1]{\makebox[\wd\widemathl][r]{$#1$}}
\newcommand\setwider[1]{\makebox[\wd\widemathr][l]{$#1$}}

\savewidel{123513251}
\savewider{12342}

\begin{align*}
    \setwidel{1} &= \setwider{2} \\
    1 &= 2 \\
\end{align*}

\begin{AuxCalc}

    \begin{align*}
        \setwidel{14312} &= 2 \\
        1 &= 12342 \\% <-- HERE IS WIDEMATHR
    \end{align*}
        
    \begin{AuxCalc2}
        \begin{align*}
            \setwidel{1} &= \setwider{2} \\
            1 &= 2 \\       
        \end{align*}
    \end{AuxCalc2}
    
    \begin{align*}
        11235132 &= \setwider{2} \\
        123513251 &= 2 \\% <-- HERE IS WIDEMATHL
    \end{align*}
    
\end{AuxCalc}


\begin{align*}
    12341 &= \setwider{2} \\
    112512351 &= 2 \\% <-- HERE IS ALSO WIDEMATHL
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply!. Although I wouldn't use this while taking notes on the fly, it still simple enought (for a new user like me) so I can use it for more formal texts. I have one question thought: after defining all new commands in the preamble, I can use the \samewide command with different arguments before each different box in the same document, right?

Comment: @MarcoCiafa Yes, for each new block of equations you want aligned, you should be able to reuse the saveboxes employed by `\savewidel` and `\savewider`.

Comment: I see there were 2 bookmarks on this question so I will wait some days before accepting your answer. Althoguh, I'm happy with it. Thank you again.